# Different background colour per sentence in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want a VBA script to change each sentence in a paragraph with a different colour.

So the script word look for a full stop (.) and then assign one colour to sentence 1 and then see a full stop and then assign a different background colour to sentence 2 etc.

You could load the script with say 10 different colours.

Is this possible?

I can't see a solution for this elsewhere online.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 2):

Showing what you have done/researched is really a must in StackOverflow. Thus, make sure that the next time you really use the search engine.

However, this was an interesting task and I usually do not do anything with Word Object, thus I have decided to give it a try:

```
Sub CountValue()

    Dim s As Long

    For s = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count

        With ActiveDocument.Sentences(s).Font

        If s Mod 2 = 0 Then
            .Color = vbBlue
            .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray10
        Else
            .Color = vbRed
            .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
        End If
        End With
    Next s

End Sub
```

This works with two colors only, but you can easily adjust it to as many as you want. It changes both font and background color:

[image]

Comment: You're going to have serious problems trying to do with in the real world, since VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following:
Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.
For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.

Comment: @macropod - Thanks, it seems that this is a pretty famous sentence & a pretty well-known problem.

Comment: It doesn't need to if it can look for full stops.  Sure that "Mt." one will render a wrong result, but bit this is clearly a rare occurrence.

Comment: yes this is an interesting one. I have an interest in educational psychology and this script is to assist people in reading text.

Comment: Well, you can always try to build up some analysis, ignoring `Mr.`, `Mrs.` `etc.`. Pretty sure that `Google` are quite advanced in this.

Comment: «It doesn't need to if it can look for full stops» - and the other sentence terminators (!?), whilst at the same time excluding decimal points and periods used for *any* form of abbreviation, such as e.g., i.e. and so on. Then there's the question of how you're going to treat bullet lists and the like - in some cases, each item is a sentence on its own but, in others, that isn't so. Good luck with that.